# Unable to run single(!) rails interactor at rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Unable to run single(!) rails interactor at rails 6. According to https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor-rails execute: rails generate interactor authenticate_user to create interactor. Command bin/rspec works perfectly and produce output:

```
Pending: (Failures listed here are expected and do not affect your suite's status)

  1) AuthenticateUser.call add some examples to (or delete) /Users/.../spec/interactors/authenticate_user_spec.rb
     # Not yet implemented
     # ./spec/interactors/authenticate_user_spec.rb:5
```

Command bin/rspec spec/interactors/authenticate_user_spec.rb to run single interactor produces error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/interactors/authenticate_user_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  RSpec.describe AuthenticateUser, type: :interactor do
    describe '.call' do
      pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
    end
  end

NameError:
  uninitialized constant AuthenticateUser
# ./spec/interactors/authenticate_user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00004 seconds (files took 0.25648 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Does anybody know how to run spec for single interactor? As far as I understand interactors dir is not autoloaded. Thanks!

Sincerely yours,
Anna

Comment: FWIW, the readme says the dir _should_ be autoloaded: "Interactor Rails ensures that app/interactors is included in your autoload paths"

Comment: A thing to try: 1) Stop the Spring pre-loader if it is running (``% spring stop`` from the command line). When you run the generator the first time it creates ``app/interactors`` folder and Spring likely won't be picking that up until it restarts.

Comment: sprint has been stopped: command "spring status"output: "Spring is not running"

Answer (score 1):

fix: default generator produce "require 'spec_helper'", it should be replaced with "require 'rails_helper'". The problem has been fixed by this replacement.